# grunt-contrib-connect: grunt server stops when browser opens

Tags: gruntjs, npm, grunt-contrib-connect

I have Grunt file like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-open');
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');

   grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      connect: {
            dev: {
                options: {
                    port: 8999,
                    livereload: 35729,
                    hostname: 'localhost'
                },
                livereload: {
                    options: {
                        open: {
                             target: 'http://localhost:8999'
                        },
                        base: [
                            'src/main'
                        ]
                    }
                 }
             }

           },

            open: {
                dev: {
                   path: 'http://localhost:<%= connect.dev.options.port %>'
                }
            }
        });

        grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:dev', 'open:dev']);
}
```

But my problem is, whenever the browseropens, the server stops prior to that.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a watch task that will watch for changed files and keep the server up:

```
watch: {
        options: {
            nospawn: true
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
            },
            files: [
                'src/main/*.js',
                'src/main/*.html'
            ]
        }
},
```

and then change the task to be:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect:dev', 'open:dev', 'watch']);
```